# Return new array from Tweets.all and loop it in view Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

Im trying to create a new array that will only contain tweets of the users you follow but im not sure how it should be done or if possible, and use that array to loop in my view

**tweets_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @tweet = Tweet.new
    
    Tweet.all.each do |tweet|
        if current_user.following?(tweet.user) || (current_user.username === tweet.user.username)  
          return @tweets << tweet
        end
      end  
  end
```

**tweets/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="tweets-container">
  <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
      <div class="tweet-feed-container">
        <strong><%= link_to "@#{tweet.user.username}", user_path(tweet.user), :class => 'tweet-username' %></strong>
        · <small><%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p") %></small><br/>
        <%= tweet.body %>

        <% tweet.tags.each do |tag| %>
          <%= link_to "#{tag.name}", tag_path(tag), :class => 'tweet-tag' %>
        <% end %>

        <% tweet.mentions.each do |mention| %>
          <%= link_to "#{mention.name}", user_path(mention.name.sub('@', '')), :class => 'tweet-tag' %>
        <% end %>

        <%= link_to '↺', retweet_tweet_path(tweet.id), method: :post, :class => 'tweet-delete' %>
        <%= link_to 'X', tweet_path(tweet), method: :delete, :class => 'tweet-delete' if current_user == tweet.user %>        
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @ayabbear, can you please share your tweet model and user model with relation? One more method that is `following?`.

Comment: @PalashBera sure will edit post one sec

Comment: hi @PalashBera, stackoverflow wont let me post the codes says i have too much code, you can check it here https://github.com/ayabbear/tweeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return all the tweets of users that current_user follows

```
@tweets = Tweet.where(user_id: current_user.followees.select(:id))
```

If you want to want include the tweets of current_user as well then use below query

```
@tweets = Tweet.where(user_id: current_user.followees.select(:id)).or(Tweet.where(user_id: current_user.id))
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer, but i think this one is different, it's returning users who's got followers. what i need was more like a filter, to only display tweets of users that i follow

Comment: @ayabbear oops my bad.. I have updated my answer, Could you please check now?

Comment: hi sampat! great! the first one is working! but the second one im getting an error "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)", i think it's the second one i need

Comment: @ayabbear I have updated my answer, could you please check now?

Comment: you're a life saver Sampat thank you! It's working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
# app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb

def index
  @tweet = Tweet.new
  @tweets = Tweet.joins(user: :followees).where("followees.follower_id = ? OR tweets.user_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id).distinct
end
```

Comment: hi palash! thanks for answering, it's giving me an error "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)"

Comment: I think you are making mistake in other place. Can you please paste first 3 lines of your error in the comment?

Comment: Hi @ayabbear, I have updated the answer. Please try with this.

Comment: hi palash! seems like im getting a syntax error, im not sure where to put the opening bracket or if there should be a closing bracket

Comment: You can try with my answer.

Comment: hi palash! it's giving me an error of ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Tweets#index :(( but it's okay tho the answer Sampat gave is working now! thank you for your time and help!